# add value of x and print total in #Python

Tags: python, printing

this code is working my questions is how can I have a total printed at the end for the value 'x'

```
      import random
      bat1 = input('enter name: ')
      x = ()
      while x != 0:
        x = random.randint(0,6)
        print(bat1 + " " + str(x))
```

Python Newbee

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
import random

bat1 = input('enter name: ')
x = ()
numbers = []
while x != 0:
    x = random.randint(0, 6)
    numbers.append(x)
    print(bat1 + " " + str(x))

print("Sum of all x: ", sum(numbers))
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Check this code:

```
import random

bat1 = input('enter name: ')
x = ()
buffer = 0
while x != 0:
    x = random.randint(0, 6)
    buffer += x
    print(bat1 + " " + str(x))

print('total ' + str(buffer ))
```

You can use a `buffer`, initialized to `0`, in which you sum the `x` value at each loop. Output example:

```
enter name: John
John 5
John 1
John 1
John 5
John 5
John 1
John 3
John 0
total 21
```

Comment: Why `numpy`? And using a lowercase `x` and an uppercase `X` sure is confusing.

Comment: I confused Python `random` with `numpy.random`. `X` or `buffer` is an opinion, in many sector this is a conventional approach.

Answer (score 1):

You should sum all of the xs!

```
import random
bat1 = input('enter name: ')
x = ()
sum = 0
while x != 0:
    x = random.randint(0,6)
    print(bat1 + " " + str(x))
    sum+=x
print("Sum:",sum)
```